# Jsoup select elements that do not have an attribute

Tags: jsoup

Is it possible to select elements that do not have a certain attribute?
For example select all elements that don't have a href attribute.

keep:

```
<a href="somelink">
```

remove:

```
<a name="jumphere">
```

I tried:

```
doc.select("a :not([href])").unwrap();
doc.select("a:not([href])").unwrap(); 
doc.select("a [href='']").unwrap();
```

none of them seem to work.

EDIT:

```
   `doc.select("a:not([href])").unwrap();` actually works!!
```

Comment: You can testdrive JSoup here: http://try.jsoup.org/ . Your second term  should work. Why the `unwrap` in this context?

Comment: yes you are right.. I don't know what I did wrong when I tested it.. Can anchors not have inner html? (not that it makes much sense I guess.) Has unwrap any downsides to remove? I guess it might be a bit less efficient because it needs to check for children, but shouldn't be that bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using an extra `()` pair that you don't need. So do it like this:

```
doc.select("a").not("[href]").unwrap();
```

Comment: @cytofu I changed it to `a:not`, I accidentally left a space in. Try it now.

Comment: then I get Could not parse query 'a:not[href]'

Comment: @cytofu Hmm, weird. Try it now, I took the not part out of the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can do it like this:

```
 Elements as = doc.select("a");
for( Element element : as )
{
if( element.attr("href").isEmpty() || element.attr("href") == null)
{
    doSomthing();
}
}
```